Software RAID 5 recovery
I had software raid 5 working like a charm, but I decided to move to other platform. After plugging drives to new computer I wanted to reassemble array but mdadm gave me an error that drives have no superblock. The only commands I used that might have affected raid was:
umount /dev/md0
mdadm --stop /dev/md0

Is there a way to recover data ?

"After plugging drives to new computer I wanted to reassemble array" - How did you ensure the drives had the same device name on the new computer? If you weren't using uuids then this is not going to end well. If you plug the drives back into the ORIGINAL computer, USING THE SAME cables, then you could change the config to use UUIds.

@symcbean my own experience is that mdadm is a lot more flexible than that now. Seems to not care as much about disk order or nominal name, is able to determine drive order in the array from superblock data.

There is no need to put into original computer. Just use mdadm --examine --scan to scan all the devices and find all the RAID superblocks.

The data should be recoverable; in fact in my experience, mdadm may have simply automatically reassembled the drive for you. What does cat /proc/mdstat say about your current status? Failing that, it may be that when you created the array you used a slightly different set of names; for instance, /dev/sda rather than /dev/sda0 or vice versa. Note that /dev/sda is the entire disk assumed to have no partition table; /dev/sda0 is the first defined partition on that disk.

cat: /proc/mdstat: No such file or directory
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda has no superblock - assembly aborted
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)

Try sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda0 /dev/sdb0 /dev/sdc0 - it looks like you have partitions defined.

it doesn't work, /dev/sd*0 doesn't exist

then there must be something strange about the way the new controller is looking at those disks. Is it possible to move the controller from the old hardware? Is it something as simple as AHCI? I gave it my best shot based on what little information you gave us, and at this point I have to bow out.

i've already put drives in old hardware and those are results. i found an old backup drive that i store few important things on it, so i guess i will have to settle for that. nevertheless thanks for trying to help. gotta do backups from now on more often

cat: /proc/mdstat: No such file or directory means you haven't loaded md modules (software RAID) into the system. Try modprobe raid456, then you should see at least empty /proc/mdstat (not emtpy, actually, it will indicate which RAID levels are now supported by there'll be no active arrays). Then mdadm --examine --scan to see what you can have at all.

Make sure you read the documentation.
The procedure is as follows:

Load the MD drivers. RAID5 is implemented by raid456 module:

modprobe raid456

(it will pull all the modules it depends on automatically). You may load other drivers too if you're using them, e.g. raid1, raid10, raid0 and linear.
That'll give you working /proc/mdstat file, which will show which RAID levels are supported currently. After the single command I suggested above it'll say:
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
unused devices: <none>


Scan your disks for RAID superblocks that are supported by the MD and dump the results into config file  (/etc/mdadm.conf or /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, whatever is used on your system):

mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf


Start the arrays:

mdadm --assemble --scan

It will search for arrays in the config file and, if found and complete, assemble and start them. If arrays not complete but have enough devices to access all the data (e.g. 1 device missing in RAID5), it won't start them, but you can still command it to start in degraded mode with mdadm --assemble --scan --run.
You may need to recreate initramfs; see your distro's documentation on how to do this.
What --scan does, it searches all the block devices in the system and checks for all known RAID metadata on them. Even if you don't know whether you built arrays out of whole devices or partitions, which type of superblock it was, it will find them. Even if devices swapped after reboot, it doesn't rely on unstable /dev/sdX names, but on UUIDs and other information in the metadata, so you're safe.
